# What do these strange parts mean?

Tags: team-fortress-2

As you guys might know, there are things in TF2 called [strange parts](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Part), add-ons to your weapons that count specific things. For example, the amount of damage you have dealt, number of allies you have extinguished, etc.

**However, I have some queries regarding how certain strange parts mean and how they count kills. Here they are:**

- **Strange Part: Freezecam Taunt Appearances**

Does this strange part only count your victim's killcam? Or does it include your taunt apperances in other people kill cam?

- **Strange Part: Full Moon Kills**

What does Valve mean by 'Full Moon Kills'? Kills during Halloween? Or on certain maps where there is a full moon?

- **Strange Part: Airborne Enemies Killed**

Does 'Airborne Enemies' include enemies that are jumping? For example, scouts that are high up in mid-air or just random enemies that jumped when you killed them.

- **Strange Part: Point-Blank Kills**

How close is 'point-blank' close?

- **Strange Part: Allied Healing Done**

How about health you have restored with a health pack that you picked up, does that count? Or dropping a sandvich. Does healing yourself count as 'allied health'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Freezecam Taunt Appearances**

Tracks the number of times you appear in enemy freezecams taunting while wearing the weapon. Similar to taunting achievements, I believe you have to be the focus of the killcam (the killer), not just in the background.

**Full Moon Kills**

It means a literal (real life) full moon. Full moons come once a month (give or take), so check your [Lunar calendar](http://www.moonconnection.com/moon_phases_calendar.phtml) for the date when a full moon will occur. On a related note, full moons coincide with the ability to equip Halloween items outside of Halloween (for those days under the full moon only).

**Airborne Enemies Killed**

'Airborne' literally means '*transported via the air*', which leads me to believe it means any character that isn't touching the ground. I don't see why they would exclude a jumping character over one that was rocket-blasted or airblasted for example.

**Point-Blank Kills**

I daresay they're using the more common definition of point-blank, ([Not the one concerned with bullet drop off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-blank_range)) i.e. within 1m (3ft). From personal experience you basically have to be bumping into the other player to get points towards this.

**Allied Healing Done**

> Adding this Strange Part to a Strange-quality weapon will enable it to track the total number of allied health points you **directly restore with that weapon**.

In other words, Sandvich, Health Packs etc do not count for this part. (Unless you can get a Strange Sandvich, in which case I want one)

---

You can see a list of all the Strange Parts on the [**TF2 Wiki**](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange_Part). If you hover over the names, a tooltip will appear with a short description of that item.

Comment: One thing - Full moon events are actually three days long, just like the real full moon.

Comment: The Strange Festive Sandvich exists. But no Strange Sandvich or Strange Buffalo Steak Sandvich. ;-;